# why is my javascript not considered secure?

Tags: javascript, html, security, authentication, video

I have a site hosted on googledrive.  Yesterday it was working, today it does not.  The problem seems to be associated with this bit of javascript which plays a select video while pausing/restarting all others:

```
function playPause(videoDivId) {
    var vid = document.getElementsByTagName('video');
    for (var i = 0, max = vid.length; i < max; i++) {
        vid[i].pause();
        vid[i].currentTime = 0;
    }
    var vidSelect = document.getElementById(videoDivId).children[0];
    vidSelect.play();
}
```

If I remove the above, the site works fine but I can't see the videos (obviously).

Google Chrome gives me the following messages:

> This page includes script from unauthenticated sources.
>
> Your connection to googledrive.com is encrypted with 128-bit
> encryption. However, this page includes other resources which are not
> secure. These resources can be viewed by others while in transit, and
> can be modified by an attacker to change the behavior of the page. The
> connection uses TLS 1.2. The connection is encrypted and authenticated
> using AES_128_GCM and uses ECDHE_ECDSA as the key exchange mechanism.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: This message is not complaining about your *code*. It's complaining about the non-encrypted stuff you've linked (apparently, a video file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error is trying to tell you, you cannot load non-HTTPS scripts on an HTTPS page.

Comment: thanks for the explanation.  turns out i was having other issues too, though i'm not sure what exactly happened.  after reloading all files to the server, all is well.